# Searching strings with Python

Tags: python

I have the following sentence:

```
Dave put the rubbish in the {{ if dave_good }}bin{{ else }}street{{ endif }}.
```

I'm currently replacing variables in text strings by capturing `[[ something ]]` and replacing the whole instance with a value *(not a problem)*. But that's using python's `re` library.

I was wondering if someone could show me how to:

1. search for single instances of `{{ if dave_good }}` in the string
2. count forward from the `{{ if dave_good }}` to make sure there is a `{{ endif }}` before the end of the string
3. if there is no `{{ else }}` then remove the tags, or the tags and their content, *(at their location in the text)* based on the boolean attribute of `dave_good`
4. if there is an `{{ else }}`

   1. if `dave_good` is `TRUE` then remove `{{ if dav_good }}` and `{{ else }}street{{ endif}}`
   2. if `dave_good` is `FALSE` then remove `{{ endif }}` and `{{ if dave_good }}bin{{ else }}`

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to write your own template language?

Comment: You should make an effort yourself first before asking here.

Comment: you might want to inspire yourself with code such as https://github.com/alexmic/microtemplates. Which does it simply and nicely without having the complexity of django/jinja2/you_name_it template language.

Comment: I was unaware of that templating language. I think I'll go that route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with [Regular Expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html).

Example:

```
import re

result = re.match("\{\{((if|else|endif).*?)\}\}","{{if 100 > 1}}",re.I)
print result.groups()

result = re.match("\{\{((if|else|endif).*?)\}\}","{{else}}",re.I)
print result.groups()

result = re.match("\{\{((if|else|endif).*?)\}\}","{{endif}}",re.I)
print result.groups()
```

Or use a template engine for python

1. [jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/)
2. [cheetah](http://www.cheetahtemplate.org/)
3. [Templating](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating)
4. [bottlepy](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/stpl.html)

Good Luck!

Comment: @LukasGraf I never said that was the way I just said it was an option, and that according to user needs.

Comment: Still, it's a dead end that doesn't allow for solving the general case, and regular expressions are simply the wrong tool for this job. Regular expressions are for matching **regular** patterns. A template language, even a dead simple one, is at least a **context free** language. See [Chomsky Hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy) and [Can regular expressions be used to match nested patterns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns)

Comment: +1 only for the template engine references

Comment: Yeah Lukas is right. Regular expressions are great for replacing all references to a variable in a string, but not good when you want to know where you are when your in a piece of code

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve only that on python then Here is something I wrote.
if its what you are asking.

```
def process(string,dave_good):
    ls=string.split(" ")
    flag=0
    flags=1
    for i in range(0,len(ls)-1):
        if ls[i]=='if' and ls[i+1]=='dave_good': #conditional if found.
            flag=1
            flags=1
            break
        flags=0

    if(flag): #expects a whitespace after endif (if theres a period then remove the     comments)
        st=i
        try:
            end=ls.index('endif')
        except:
            flags=0
            pass
        #    try:
         #       end=ls.index('endif.')
         #   except:
          #      print "no matching endif"
           #    flags=0

    if(flags):# delete 'if','else','endif' and corresponding variables(bin/streets)
        if dave_good:
            del ls[st]
            del ls[st]
            del ls[st+1]
            del ls[st+1]
            del ls[st+1]
        else:
            del ls[st]
            del ls[st]
            del ls[st]
            del ls[st]
            del ls[st+1]
        return " ".join(ls)#join back to a string

print process('Dave put the rubbish if in the if dave_good bin else street endif .',True)
print process('Dave put if else the rubbish in the if dave_good bin else street endif',False)
```

**It might not be what exactly you are looking for but it can be a good start**
Also for the third condition you can put a check for else condition and remove data similarly